# The correct method of utilizing connection pooling

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, sockets

I am currently developing a server and one of its functions is retrieving data from the server when `database`, `query`, `credentials`, etc are supplied from the client. I am also using `socket.io` to stream 100 rows from server at a time.

Since I am not sure how many concurrent requests will be made to the database at once at peak, I have set up `connectionPool` using `mssql` node module. Below is succinctly how my code looks like.

```
socket.on('request:database', (connectionConf) => {

    let query = connectionConf.query;
    let dbAddress = connectionConf.dbAddress;
    let id = connectionConf.id;
    let password = connectionConf.password;
    let dbName = connectionConf.dbName;
    let requestedRows = parseInt(connectionConf.noOfRows);
    let createExcel = connectionConf.excel;

    const sqlConfig = {
        user: id,
        password: password,
        server: dbAddress,
        database: dbName,
        pool: {
            max: 1,
            min: 0,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
        },
        options: {
            encrypt: true,
        }
    };

    let connectionPool = new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig, err => 

        request.stream = true;

        request.query(query);

        request.on('recordset', columns => {
            //run functions with columns

            socket.emit('response:headers', //send results);

            // Emitted once for each recordset in a query
        });

        request.on('row', row => {
            //Run some functions
            socket.emit('result', //send 100 rows at a time);

            // Emitted for each row in a recordset
        });
    )
});
```

In the above code, `request:database` `socket.io` event is triggered every time client makes a query. The problem is that I am not utilizing the pool correctly as I am creating new `connectionPool` every time client clicks send query button.

So, I cannot create connection pool prior to the button click because they are provided from the client

> How do I resolve this connection pooling issue so that I can configure db connection with the data that is provided by the client and at the same time reuse same pool with several end point users?

Comment: How about putting the `connectionPool` variable in a wider scope and checking if its `undefined` before creating new pools?

Comment: @nilobarp but then how would I know the credentials for connection if I create the pool before information is submitted?

Comment: You need to refactor your code to allow clients to join a channel before requesting a database object. That way clients can submit configuration during subscription call and we will be able to utilize connection pooling.